# Flex container with items of variable size

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I need to display a horizontal list of images using Flex. I can't use a horizontal TileList because the tiles all end up the size of the first item. Is there a flex control that will allow me to have items with different sizes?

Edit: The list of items would ideally come from a data provider.  Unfortunately the control in Chetan Sastry's answer only supports data providers if the items have a fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code segment where I do what I think you're describing. The images are various sizes, but this displays them in a squared-up grid. The trick (at least for my requirements) is to set the height and minWidth for the container that goes into each cell.

```
<mx:TileList id="imgTiles" width="100%" height="100%"  
      paddingTop="2" paddingBottom="2" paddingLeft="2" paddingRight="2"  
      itemClick="eTilesClick(event)">     
    <mx:itemRenderer>  
        <mx:Component>  
            <mx:VBox horizontalAlign="center"  
                   height="250" minWidth="150"  
                   horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"  
                   borderColor="#D2D2D2" borderThickness="1"
                   borderStyle="solid">
                <mx:Label text="{data.imageCaption}" height="15" fontSize="10" fontWeight="bold"/>
                <mx:Image source="{data.thumbnailUrl}" width="100%"/>
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:TileList>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about an [HBox](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/containers/HBox.html) with a [Repeater](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Repeater.html) for your images?